# Word 365 ActiveX Command Button Wordwrap Issue

Tags: microsoft-word, activex

Silly little problem - Using Word 365, .docm file that has an ActiveX Command Button.
The button does what it should when clicked, but...

The button's Caption is quite long, so I turned WordWrap on in the properties, and the cation text immediately wrapped to show all the text.

The problem is that as soon as I turn off Design Mode the button goes back to behaving as if WordWrap is off.

I've tried with Autosize on and off. I've saved, closed, and re-opened the doc, and while the value of the WordWrap property stays as True, the Caption text is always displayed as if it's 'False'.

Anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: Active X died a while back. Is that maybe the issue?

Comment: Probably - Just couldn't find another button control in the list.
Anyway, luckily it's not important, just a bit annoying.